# Conflicting types error and pointer from integer without cast warning C

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, warnings, read-write

I am trying to learn read/write programs in C and I found an example online that I thought I should start studying. When I tried compiling the code though, I get a few warnings and one error like this:

```
read.c:21:8: error: conflicting types for ‘write’
 void * write(void *temp) {
        ^
In file included from read.c:11:0:
/usr/include/unistd.h:369:16: note: previous declaration of ‘write’ was here
 extern ssize_t write (int __fd, const void *__buf, size_t __n) __wur;
                ^
read.c: In function ‘write’:
read.c:25:4: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 ret=pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
    ^
read.c: In function ‘write_2’:
read.c:45:4: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 ret=pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
    ^
read.c: At top level:
read.c:106:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main() {
```

I'm still very new to C programming and I couldn't figure out how to get these warnings and error solved, since I just jumped into this topic without knowing the language too well. Here's the code I'm trying to compile.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*
From the output we can see that the two writes were executed one after the other. But in case of reads, even though read_1 had not unlocked the rwlock, read_2 was allowed into the critical section and read the file. That shows us that multiple readers are allowed but only one writer is allowed into the critical section. 
*/
pthread_rwlock_t rwlock; // allows multiple readers to access the resource, but only one reader at any given time.




void * write(void *temp) {
char *ret;
FILE *file1;
char *str;
ret=pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
printf("\nFile locked, please enter the message \n");
str=(char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
file1=fopen("temp","w");
scanf("%s",str);
fprintf(file1,"%s",str);
fclose(file1);
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
printf("\nUnlocked the file you can read it now \n");
return ret;
}




void * write_2(void *temp) {
char *ret;
FILE *file1;
char *str;
sleep(3);
ret=pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
printf("\nFile locked, please enter the message \n");
str=(char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
file1=fopen("temp","a");
scanf("%s",str);
fprintf(file1,"%s",str);
fclose(file1);
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
printf("\nUnlocked the file you can read it now \n");
return ret;
}





void * read_1(void *temp) {
char *ret;
FILE *file1;
char *str;
sleep(5);
pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);
printf("\n1 Opening file for reading\n");
file1=fopen("temp","r");
str=(char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
fscanf(file1,"%s",str);
printf("\nMessage from file is %s \n",str);
sleep(3);

fclose(file1);
printf("\nUnlocking rwlock\n");
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
return ret;
}





void * read_2(void *temp) {
char *ret;
FILE *file1;
char *str;
sleep(6);
pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);
printf("\n2 Opening file for reading\n");
file1=fopen("temp","r");
str=(char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
fscanf(file1,"%s",str);
printf("\nMessage from file is %s \n",str);

fclose(file1);

pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);

return ret;
}




main() {

pthread_t thread_id,thread_id1,thread_id3,thread_id4;
pthread_attr_t attr;
int ret;
void *res;
pthread_rwlock_init(&rwlock,NULL);
ret=pthread_create(&thread_id,NULL,&write,NULL);
ret=pthread_create(&thread_id1,NULL,&read_1,NULL);

ret=pthread_create(&thread_id3,NULL,&read_2,NULL);

ret=pthread_create(&thread_id4,NULL,&write_2,NULL);
printf("\n Created thread");
pthread_join(thread_id,&res);
pthread_join(thread_id1,&res);
pthread_join(thread_id3,&res);

pthread_join(thread_id4,&res);
pthread_rwlock_destroy(&rwlock);
}
```

Question is why are these warnings and this error showing up for this code?

P.S. not sure why but when I try to run it after getting these warning and errors, it still runs the way I thought it would. It's quite odd. Thank you for reading.

Comment: `write` is a library function so the compiler doesn’t like it when another one is defined. Change the name to `write_1` or something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) is the name of a system call. The *declaration* for the function is present in `<unistd.h>` which you have included into your C program.

Your C program continues to work because nowhere are you using the *actual* `write` system call; the C standard library uses it but it is linked to that *other* `write` function statically.

---

As for the other warnings,

```
main()
```

is not proper C at all. It needs to have prototype of either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

For `pthread_*` functions you **must** `#include <pthread.h>`.

The return value of `pthread_rwlock_wrlock` is **not** a pointer, but `int`, so you must assign it to an object of type `int`, yet you assign it to `ret` which is of type `char *`

---

All in all, you should turn on all generally helpful diagnostics in the C compiler (`-Wall`), and consider each warning an error (`-Werror`).

---

Finally, all compilation and linking command lines should have the `-pthread` flag on them.

Comment: Since the original post provides no info about that, I'd mention that there is also need for `-pthread` flag.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my code. Is there a reason why I'm getting these warnings now? I changed the ret type but still getting warnings for return type makes pointer from integer without a cast.

Comment: @JustinK.Maddox you're never supposed to **change** the **question** after it has been answered, only refine. Please ask your new question separately.